# UPDATE - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: order_detail and product_attribute.

I have a field called available_date in product_attribute, and I want to copy values to `f_fabricacion` in order_detail.

id_product_attribute in product_attribute and product_attribute_id in order_details have to be the same.

I have tried to do this update, but it wont work.

```
UPDATE order_detail
SET f_fabricacion = SELECT a.available_date FROM a.product_attribute, b.b2_order_detail WHERE a.id_product_attribute = b.product_attribute_id
```

What could I do?

Thanks.

Comment: read about update with join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
UPDATE order_detail o JOIN product_attribute p 
ON p.id_product_attribute = o.product_attribute_id
SET o.f_fabricacion = p.available_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do as per below-

```
UPDATE order_detail od 
join product_attribute pa on pa.id_product_attribute = od.product_attribute_id 
set od.f_fabricacion = pa.available_date;
```

If you want to update only few rows with any condition then use as per below-

```
UPDATE order_detail od 
join product_attribute pa on pa.id_product_attribute = od.product_attribute_id 
set od.f_fabricacion = pa.available_date
where column_name="value";
```